# How do I decide between different forecasting model families to automate forecasting for 150 time series?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, forecast

I have weekly time series data for multiple departments (retail domain) and based on some research, I am automating the process of finding model parameters for each time series. So far, I have implemented the following models for each time series in a for loop:

1) ARIMA (auto.arima in R)

2) stlf (cannot use R's ets function since I have weekly data)

3) TBATS

4) Regression on ARIMA errors (using fourier terms)

5) Baseline models: naive & mean

I want to understand how to choose models for each time series. I have multiple approaches to this:

1) Choose model with lowest RMSE on test data (risk: overfitting on test data)

2) Choose model with lowest RMSE best on cross-validation of time series (tsCV)

3) Choose one family of models for all the time series based on which family gives lowest average RMSE score across all the time series.

Are there any ways I can improve my approach? Any disadvantages to any of the above approaches? Any better approach?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Forecast your data with all forecasting methods mentioned above, after that calculate the MAPE and check which model is giving best results then use that model for forecast your data.
Also try to check with different different data transformation like log, inverse, etc.. for your input data.